# OpenVINO output key error after conversion from ONNX

Tags: python, openvino

I've converted a (modified) Darknet model to onnx, (tried opset 10 & 11) and then converting this onnx model into IR using [this (at the bottom)](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_ONNX.html)

Everything seems to be OK

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\model_optimizer>python mo.py --input_model C:\dev\yolo\weights\export.onnx --progress --output_dir C:\dev\yolo\weights\
Model Optimizer arguments:
Common parameters:
        - Path to the Input Model:      C:\dev\yolo\weights\export.onnx
        - Path for generated IR:        C:\dev\yolo\weights\
        - IR output name:       export
        - Log level:    ERROR
        - Batch:        Not specified, inherited from the model
        - Input layers:         Not specified, inherited from the model
        - Output layers:        Not specified, inherited from the model
        - Input shapes:         Not specified, inherited from the model
        - Mean values:  Not specified
        - Scale values:         Not specified
        - Scale factor:         Not specified
        - Precision of IR:      FP32
        - Enable fusing:        True
        - Enable grouped convolutions fusing:   True
        - Move mean values to preprocess section:       False
        - Reverse input channels:       False
ONNX specific parameters:
Model Optimizer version:
Progress: [....................] 100.00% done
[ SUCCESS ] Generated IR version 10 model.
[ SUCCESS ] XML file: C:\dev\yolo\weights\export.xml
[ SUCCESS ] BIN file: C:\dev\yolo\weights\export.bin
[ SUCCESS ] Total execution time: 10.24 seconds.
```

When I try to load this model using the provided YOLO sample from [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2019_R1/_inference_engine_ie_bridges_python_sample_object_detection_demo_yolov3_async_README.html), loading is fine, but when I inspect the net object in debug mode I see that the outputs are
`Transpose_231`, `Transpose_237` and `Slice_230/Split.1`.
When I inspect the layers, I see it contains `Transpose_231`, `Transpose_237` and `Slice_230/Split` (note, missing `.1` in the split)

This causes the sample to fail with `KeyError: 'Slice_230/Split.1'` in

```
    for layer_name, out_blob in output.items():
        out_blob = out_blob.buffer.reshape(net.layers[net.layers[layer_name].parents[0]].out_data[0].shape)
```

If I inspect the IR's .XML file I don't see any `.1` in it

```
        <layer id="214" name="Slice_230/Split" type="VariadicSplit" version="opset1">
            <input>
                <port id="0">
                    <dim>6</dim>
                    <dim>142191</dim>
                </port>
                <port id="1"/>
                <port id="2">
                    <dim>3</dim>
                </port>
            </input>
            <output>
                <port id="3" precision="FP32">
                    <dim>4</dim>
                    <dim>142191</dim>
                </port>
                <port id="4" precision="FP32">
                    <dim>1</dim>
                    <dim>142191</dim>
                </port>
                <port id="5" precision="FP32">
                    <dim>1</dim>
                    <dim>142191</dim>
                </port>
            </output>
        </layer>
```

Any suggestions where this `.1` comes from?

**EDIT**

Tried using opset 9, the same thing happens only this time with `Slice_174/Split` & `Slice_174/Split.1`

Answer (score 0):

The split-1 is actually a Category of Data movement operations. It Split operation splits an input tensor into pieces of the same length along some axis.

This Split operation splits the *"data"* input tensor into pieces of the same length along *"axis"*. The i-th shape of output tensor will be equal to the *"data"* shape except along dimension *"axis"* where the shape will be data.shape[i]/num_splits. The sum of elements of split_lengths must match data.shape[axis].

One of the example:

```
<layer id="1" type="Split" ...>
    <data num_splits="3" />
    <input>
        <port id="0">       <!-- some data -->
            <dim>6</dim>
            <dim>12</dim>
            <dim>10</dim>
            <dim>24</dim>
        </port>
        <port id="1">       <!-- axis: 1 -->
        </port>
    </input>
    <output>
        <port id="2">
            <dim>6</dim>
            <dim>4</dim>
            <dim>10</dim>
            <dim>24</dim>
        </port>
        <port id="3">
            <dim>6</dim>
            <dim>4</dim>
            <dim>10</dim>
            <dim>24</dim>
        </port>
        <port id="4">
            <dim>6</dim>
            <dim>4</dim>
            <dim>10</dim>
            <dim>24</dim>
        </port>
    </output>
</layer>
```

You may refer here for further info: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_ops_movement_Split_1.html